# In Chip 'n Dale, are they male or female chipmunks?

Tags: character, chip-n-dale

In Chip 'n Dale, are they male or female chipmunks?

[image]

Comment: The screenshot you show is from Chip & Dale: Rescue Rangers in which Chip and Dale are male along with Monte. Gadget was female.

Comment: Dale is a girl and chip is a boy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a long time, there was nothing specific about the two chipmunks to clearly identify their sex within the old cartoons.

From [Disney's own site](https://disneyland.disney.go.com/attractions/disneyland/chip-n-dale-treehouse/):

> *Who's Who?*
>
> Ever wonder how to tell **these 2 chipmunk brothers** apart? Chip has a small black nose with 2 teeth in the center of his mouth. Dale has a big red nose and 2 buck teeth with a gap in the middle.

So, if the official line is that they are "brothers", then they must, by definition, both be male.

Historically, it wasn't until the show [*Chip 'n' Dale: Rescue Rangers*](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Chip_%27n_Dale_Rescue_Rangers) that they were ever given clothes or fleshed out personalities. The clothes and personalities are generally male, and there are at least two instances where both of the brothers exhibit an attraction towards female characters.

Tammy the squirrel in [Adventures in Squirrelsitting](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Adventures_in_Squirrelsitting)

[image: tammy and chip]

Foxglove the bat in [Good Times, Bat Times](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Good_Times,_Bat_Times)

[image: tammy the bat]

Comment: Wouldn't the statement "these two brothers" imply they are both male? The question would be, when were they first referred to as brothers?

Comment: @JohnP What source are you quoting? The problem I was running into was that all the Disney wiki's and everything were unofficial and/or unsourced until Rescue Rangers. Disney's official site calling them "brothers" is all the word-of-god that's really necessary though.

Comment: @JohnP, NM. I see what you're saying. That's pretty much what I was getting at. Guess I didn't explain it well enough.

Comment: Dale attracted to a female? I don't buy it.

Comment: That link is broken now, it redirects to Disney's attractions.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Disney Comics Wiki](http://disneycomics.wikia.com/wiki/Chip_%27n%27_Dale) about Chip & Dale:

> Their earliest acquaintances were two girlfriends that they both shared, Clarice and Chi-Chi (why they didn't just date one each is unknown).

Also:

> They also shared twin nephews, Zip 'n' Zap, and had a common Grandpa (as well as other relatives), which raises the possibility that they are related, perhaps even brothers (they certainly act like siblings).

Plus the page lists them as male in their biobox.

And from [Comicvine's entry on Dale](http://www.comicvine.com/dale/4005-4586/):

> He is brother to Chip, they are both on the "Rescue Rangers."

And from [Magical Mouse Schoolhouse](http://www.magicalmouseschoolhouse.com/2013/07/tiggerific-tuesday-trivia-chip-dale-brothers/):

> According to author Dave Smith in his Disney Trivia from the Vault, *Bill Justice, the animator who first drew the rascally chipmunks Chip & Dale, wrote in his autobiography 50 years after the characters were created that he thought of the two as* **“simply little brothers,”** although the Walt Disney Company has never stated if they were brothers or just good friends.

And from the [Disneyland](https://disneyland.disney.go.com/attractions/disneyland/chip-n-dale-treehouse/)* website:

> Ever wonder how to tell these 2 chipmunk **brothers** apart?

(*© Disney, All Rights Reserved, Disney Parks & Travel)

This all seems to point to male.

Answer (score 3):

Just go to the [Chip 'n Dale Rescue Rangers wikiquote page](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Chip_'n_Dale_Rescue_Rangers) and do control-F (or Command-F on a Mac) to search for the word "he" on the page, you can find various lines where the characters were referred to as "he", like this one from *Kiwi's Big Adventure*:

> [When Gadget finds out Dale is faking]
>
> Gadget: Why that little...! He couldn't...! How did...! OOOOH!!
>
> Chip: I know just what you mean.

And this one from *To the Rescue: Part V*:

> Chip: Courage and our friendship binding us together! So follow me!
>   We've got a date with a ruby!
>
> Monty: He's bonkers in the conkers, ya know.
>
> Dale: Yeah? But he is my friend.

(Dale's line here about Chip being his "friend" suggests the writer probably didn't imagine them as brothers at the time, regardless of what the people writing the websites quoted by phantom42 and Meat Trademark thought)